# SQL Between Function - Wrong Data is reflecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008

I am trying to extract the data using between function but wrong data is reflecting
below SQL query i am using,

```
select * from ORDERSTATUS where ORDERDATE BETWEEN '25-07-2017' AND '31-08-2017';
```

Also when i run below sql query to extract the data of particular date, i am getting correct output.

```
select * from ORDERSTATUS where ORDERDATE = '31-08-2017'
```

Please help me....

and below is the design of my table,

```
[VENCD] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[VENNAME] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[ITEMCD] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ITEMNAME] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[SKUCD] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SKUNAME] [varchar](255) NULL,
[OORDERNO] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[INVNO] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OQTY] [int] NOT NULL,
[COD] [int] NOT NULL,
[SELLINGPRICE] [int] NOT NULL,
[ORDERTYPE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DSP] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DOCKETNO] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MANIFESTID] [varchar](100) NULL,
**[ORDERDATE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,**
[CANCELDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SHIPP_INST_DATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[INVOUTDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PICKUPDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[REALDELDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DELCOMPDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[RETURNREGDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SHIPP_CANCELDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[RTODATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DRDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROSSSTAGE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[REFUND] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CHNLCODE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CHNLCLASS] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HLCN] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MLCN] [varchar](50) NULL,
[COMMPERC] [int] NULL,
[EXCHCANCELDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[RETURNCANCELDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TYPE] [varchar](50) NULL
```

Comment: You're storing OrderDate as a varchar(50)? is there a reason you're not storing this as a datetime or datetime2?

Comment: your ORDERDATE  contains varchar datatype, then how could you use between function.

Comment: okay i understood. but is there any alternate way?

Comment: CONVERT(datetime,OrderDate) and use that in your where clauses

Comment: @RichBenner The convert might fail because the format the date is stored in the varchar field is not a language neutral format.

Comment: The solution is to use a proper, unambiguous format, such as YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Better would be to convert the OrderDate column from varchar to datetime or datetime2

Comment: I concur w/ @GuidoG. Note that the suggestions using to Convert will also harm your query's performance because index can't be used in this way. At very least, consider adding a computed column that's persisted so that you can index and query it instead just like a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change where clause with this?

```
CONVERT (DATETIME, ORDERDATE, 105)  BETWEEN '20170725' AND '20170831';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ORDERDATE) BETWEEN '20170725' AND '20170831'
```